# Excel - If the value is already present in the above rows, then its option A else option B

Tags: excel

I am looking to check if a value is already present in the above rows of a column using an excel formula. If it is already present then the output is "yes" else it is a "No"

For Example,

```
Name Present
AS    No
AD    No
AF    No
AS    Yes
AS    Yes
AD    Yes
```

My values are there in the column Name and the expected outputs are there in the column Present.

We can do this using Macro but is there an excel formula that can help us get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **B7** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A6,A7)>0,"yes","No")
```

and copy **upwards** through **B2**

[image]